# FB JS-API: GraphMethodException "unsupported get request" when accessing foreign profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I wrote a facebook app using the Javascript API and want to display the name of another user using the app (I only know the facebook ID of the other user). The users are not friends of each other.

I'm logged in with the first user and call

```
FB.api('/'+id_of_second_user, function(result) {alert(result);});
```

Returns a GraphMethodException with the message "Unsupported Get request".

Calling http://graph.facebook.com/[id_of_second_user] in browser works correctly when I'm logged in to facebook as the first user.

I don't understand why, for the call using the browser shouldn't have more rights than the API call via the Javascript API (at least the app has an application token and a user is logged in using FB.login. Both is false for the direct request using the browser)

Do I have to use a native ajax call to http://graph.facebook.com/[id_of_second_user] or can I use the Javascript API for this?